# UiPath searching for an item that is not available in amazon and display item not found

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-api

When we search for an item that is not available in the amazon and instead of that the products related to that item name is showing. I need to display a message that item is not found. How that can be done in UiPath?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `Element Exists` activity:

[image: Amazon Element Exists]

With that you set a proper `Selector` like I did. Make sure the `Selector` is unique on all the needed Amazon sites.

That `ElementExists` variable now represents if your `Selector` is found.

Here another image how to check it. I used the `Click` activity but you can easily replace it with the `Element Exists` activity:

[image: amazon click iphone 11 s]

Comment: Thank You for your time,but there is a problem. If I search for an apple iphone 11 s, the result will be other phones like iphone 11 pro or max will display.The iPhone 11 s still remains in the search box. If I use ElementExists activity it will locate the element in the search box. Actually I need a message like item not found. Please help me.

Comment: Does it work now? You should definitely play around and maybe also have a look on the UiPath Academy. Really helpful and good for beginners. Hope you create beautiful robot processes in the future. All the best.

Comment: Yes It really worked. I am a beginner in UiPath.Thank you  so much for the support.

Comment: Nice. Please accept the answer and we can close this topic =)